# How I can compare Null entity without throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, nullpointerexception

I have a method who gets some data with Hibernate, but if the entity is Null, when I try to compare with it throws `NullPointerException`

ExampleController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/example/{exampleId}")
    public String exampleMethod(@PathVariable("exampleId") final Integer exampleId, final ModelMap model) {

        ExampleEntity ee = this.ExampleEntityService.load(exampleId);
        if (ee.exampleAnidatedEntity() == null) {
            model.addAttribute("exampleAnidatedEntity", ee.exampleAnidatedEntity());
        } else {
            model.addAttribute("exampleAnidatedEntity", new ExampleAnidatedEntity());
        }

// Do some stuff...
```

Comment: Check whether something else is returning null. For Example ee.

Comment: I suspect you need `if ( ee == null || e.example... == null)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this to

```
if (ee!=null && ee.exampleAnidatedEntity() == null) {
```

This will make the checking only when `ee` is not null.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are using session.load() to fetch the object
**"If load() can’t find the object in the cache or database, an exception is thrown. The load() method never returns null. The get() method returns null if the object can’t be found."**

ref http://goo.gl/wmi2bf

In this case you need to handle null pointer exception while getting **ee** object.

```
try{
    this.ExampleEntityService.load(exampleId);
   }catch(Exception ne){
        /**handle exception**/
   }
```

If you are using get() then ee can be null, in that case null check will be

```
if (null==ee) {
     return; 
}
if (ee.exampleAnidatedEntity() == null){
/**handle null**/
} else {
/** handle not null**/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do it like this ,it will be better

```
if (ee !=null && ee.exampleAnidatedEntity() == null) {}
```